# adding escape character to a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var x = 'It\'s \@lright';
var y = "We are the so-called \"Vikings\" from the north.";
var i;
var s = "";
var z = "Thi$ is * a@ demo";
var patt = "[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]";
for(i=0;i<z.length;i++){
  if(z[i].match(patt)){
    s+= "\\"+z[i];
  }
  else{
    s+= z[i];
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + "<br>" + y + "<br>" + s;  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output for the above script I get is :

> It's @lright
>   We are the so-called "Vikings" from the north.
>   Thi\$ is \* a\@ demo

I don't know why for the strings `x` and `y`, if I add any special character followed by `'\'` (backslash), strings are displayed as it is with the special characters. But when I do it to string s by appending `'\'` before each special character, the string gets displayed with `'\'` preceding the special characters.

Can someone explain me this? And also please tell me how to add '\' before each special character in such a way that when I print the string I only see the special characters (not with `'\'` prepended in front of them as happening now)?

Comment: appending before something is [prepending](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepend).

Comment: @Amy Ok. My bad...

Answer (score 1):

> why for the strings x and y, if I add any special character followed by '\'(backslash), strings are displayed as it is with the special characters

Because the escape character is part of string literal syntax, and you create `x` and `y` with string literals.

When the JavaScript source code is parsed into a string primitive, the escape sequences are converted to the characters they represent.

> But when I do it to string s by appending '\' before each special character

Because then you aren't using string literals. `"\\"` is a string literal and the escape character followed by the backslash becomes a backslash in the data of the string primitive.

When you concatenate that with another string primitive, you are no longer at the *parsing source code* stage, you have a backslash *in the data*.

> And also please tell me how to add '\' before each special character in such a way that when I print the string I only see the special characters(not with '\' appended in front of them as happening now)?

Do nothing. The data already has the special characters in it.

It doesn't make sense to take something which already exists in the form you want, and then modify it to get the form you want.

Comment: I think the question is more centered around, why does `var z = "Thi$ is * a@ demo";` get rendered with slashes in it when setting `innerHTML`

Comment: But I need to add ''\" before special characters because they create problem when I send them in json object

Comment: @mhodges yes I am asking about this.. exactly

Comment: @mhodges — As the second section of this answer says: Because they are being explicitly added.

Comment: @Garry — That suggests you are doing something wrong when you are creating your JSON and that you [asked the wrong question](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Quentin what's wrong in this question? I just asked about a simple behaviour of strings in javascript

Comment: @Garry — Because you seem to have a practical problem that you aren't asking about.

Comment: The for loop has the problem, removing it solves it.

Comment: @Zekrom_Vale removing the for loop? I don't get it. In the for loop I am prepending \ to each special character

Comment: @Garry — Which, as I said in the last section of the answer, is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character is the indicator of a string escape character. When it is found in a string, the JavaScript runtime knows that the character that will follow it dictates what actual character to escape. If you just want to include a single backslash, then you'll have to provide the escape code for that, which is two backslashes.

```js
console.log("\"This string has double quotes embedded within double quotes\"");

// If we want to output a single backslash, we need to escape with with \\
// So, if we want to produce two of them, we need \\\\
console.log("The escape code for a \\ is \\\\");

console.log("The escape code for a \' is \\'");

console.log("The escape code for a \" is \\\"");
```

Now, it's important to distinguish a "JavaScript" string escape sequence with an HTML entity code.

If you take a JavaScript string that includes JavaScript escape characters and send that string to be parsed by the HTML parser, the escape sequences will have already been processed and the HTML parser will be receiving the result of that work. The HTML parser will just render the actual characters that were passed as it normally would.

The JavaScript escape characters only have meaning when processed by the JavaScript runtime, not the HTML parser:

```js
var x = "This will be split over two lines when processed by the JavaScript runtime, \n\nbut the escape code will will just cause normal carriage return white space for the HTML parser";

var y = "\"To escape or not to escape\"";

// Escape code will be parsed and result in two groups of text
alert(x);

// Here, the result of the escaping will be passed to the HTML parser for further processing

// But here, the new line characters embedded within the string will be treated as all exteraneous
// white space in an HTML document is - - it will be normalized down to a single space.
document.querySelector("#d1").innerHTML = x;
document.querySelector("#d2").innerHTML = y;
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

Comment: I think the question is more centered around, why does `var z = "Thi$ is * a@ demo";` get rendered with slashes in it when setting `innerHTML`

Comment: @mhodges Yes, I was working on an update to my answer to address this.

Comment: @Zekrom_Vale Yes, you can, but that was not what the question was about.